# ZNID24xx-Router public IP

Tags: networking, ip, router

I need to make my public IP the same as my internal one.

My router is ZNID24xx-Router, and i'm trying to change the config of port forwarding, but i'm not certain this is the right thing to do and i haven't yet succeeded in creating a new rule.

Core problem is that i need to send differents IP to the same service (i know it sounds fishy, but it's actually related to some awful legacy system, and the inflexibility to change the end service). I already set up a proxy server (Squid) with the IP's hardcoded and a random acl, but the end service is still getting the same IP.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I can't figure out what you are asking. Try to make the question a bit more clear.

Comment: Ok, key points are:

endPoint

need to get diferents IP from the same origin (i know is somehow ilegal, but this company owns the sender and the receiver, it's just that the legacy system is not going to change under any circumstances)


i think the router is changing the ip (public ip, 'cause the message goes over internet). Is that why i'm fighting to the death agains the router.


i tried with a proxy server, but it was BETWEEN me and the router, so it ended up with the proxied IP changed